# primitivity of a polynomial over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that we have a polynomial 
$f(x)=ax^3-bx^2+cx-d\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then $f(x)$ will be called primitive if $(a,b,c,d)=1$

I have been told that over a field $F$ there is no notion of primitivity? Could someone explain to me why is that?

Thank you

Comment: In what context was the remark made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integral domain $R$, one can define a primitive polynomial over $R$ as one whose coefficients have no common $R$-divisors besides units. That is, $f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i \in R[x]$ is primitive if $b | a_i$ for all $i$ implies $b$ is a unit.  (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial). It's the second definition).

Note that, if If $R = \mathbb Z$, this coincides with your definition.

This definition makes perfect sense for a field, which is in particular an integral domain. But that doesn't mean the definition is interesting: the coefficients of any nonzero polynomial over a field have no common divisors besides units, since any nonzero element of the field is a unit. Hence, every nonzero polynomial over a field is primitive.

If someone has told you that there is "no notion of a primitive polynomial over a field," my guess would be that they really meant "there is no *meaningful* notion of a primitive polynomial over a field." It doesn't mean that you can't define primitivity over a field, just that it's not going to give you anything new so it's superfluous.

Comment: Thank you. So if we take some exapmple, say $f(x)=3x^3-5x^2+2$, over $\mathbb{Z}$ $f(x)$ is primitive as $(2,3,5)=1$, how does the situation look like over $\mathbb{Q}$? Is $f(x)$ also primitive over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, it is primitive over $\mathbb Q$ because $\mathbb Q$ is a field, so every nonzero polynomial is primitive. It just isn't particularly meaningful to say that a polynomial is primitive over $\mathbb Q$, because that property on its own doesn't distinguish it from other nonzero polynomials over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we should say every nonzero polynomial over a field is primitive, since any nonzero coefficient generates the ideal $F$ (blows up).

All nonzero elements being invertible means we can take the polynomial to be monic (unless it's zero) by factoring out the *unit* (invertible) leading coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Over a field, the gcd of any collection of elements is $1$, unless the elements are all zero, and then the gcd is $0$. So over a field every non-zero polynomial would be primitive.

Comment: Thank you, short and concrete explanation.